# Cannot start / assign workflows; after Publishing the Workflow disappears (Sharepoint Designer 2013 Workflows)

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, 2016, workflow-manager

I cannot create new Designer Workflows (2013, very basic: create a workflow history entry).

What I tested so far:

1. Okay to be honest: I can create new ones and they are correctly published and assigned to the list (according SharePoint Designer) but from the UI they are not available. 
   [image]
2. I exported a Workflow from another site and imported it. This worked fine without any issues, it will show up in the UI but it shows an error after trying to manually starting it.
   [image]

If I try to publish this workflow from the Designer, it disappears from the UI...

3. After some search I found the following error in the ULS logs:

   Microsoft.Workflow.Client.InvalidRequestException: The scope '/SharePoint/default/b2ab4fc9-e61d-4eba-a8e0-1412d9fc30e4/6db43c86-9efe-49b3-b4a5-8e42a6920783' has no workflows under it. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: 3fbeea12-858c-4ed4-a896-f48ed6182cb0. NodeId: VM-BIE-SP-PROD1. Scope: /SharePoint/default/b2ab4fc9-e61d-4eba-a8e0-1412d9fc30e4/6db43c86-9efe-49b3-b4a5-8e42a6920783. Client ActivityId : c4458d9e-d196-70be-3701-6bb329548336. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
4. After some more google-based-search, I tried the following things:

   - Flush DNS
   - Recycle workflow manager in the IIS
   - restarted Service Bus Gateway, SErvice Bus Message Broker, Workflow Manager Backend

Does anyone has another ideas / hints etc...?

Comment: I think I know about this issue.  Off the top of my head I think it affects reusable workflows, you should be able to locate the workflow via the Sharepoint Designer menus.  If you've not used Designer before, it is free Microsoft software.

Comment: I know the designer: it appears in the designer and I can publish it. But it will not show up in the UI to start the workflow manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a subsite created below the site collection the Workflows worked fine.

So I deactivated in the site collection the feature WorkflowServiceStore and activated it again - now it works fine :-)

```
  Disable-SPFeature -Identity WorkflowServiceStore –Url https://sharepoint.com -Confirm:$false
  Enable-SPFeature -Identity WorkflowServiceStore –Url https://sharepoint.com
```